# How much data to optimize our queries

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, query-optimization

i have one table with this stracture and Indexs

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Report4](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Mesc] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Line] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [Unit] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
    [ST_CODE] [nvarchar](5) NULL,
    [PbsNo] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [PbsDate] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [PbsQty] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [PbsQtyRec] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [QtyConsum1] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [QtyConsum2] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [QtyConsum3] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [QtyConsum4] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [QtyConsum5] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [Type] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [InvQty] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [TypeRequest] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [HeaderId] [bigint] NULL,
    [LOCATION] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Report4] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [HeaderId] ON [dbo].[Report4]
(
    [HeaderId] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [Id],
[Mesc],
[Line],
[Unit],
[Description],
[ST_CODE],
[PbsNo],
[PbsDate],
[PbsQty],
[PbsQtyRec],
[QtyConsum1],
[QtyConsum2],
[QtyConsum3],
[QtyConsum4],
[QtyConsum5],
[Type],
[InvQty],
[TypeRequest]) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [HeaderIdRAll] ON [dbo].[Report4]
(
    [HeaderId] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [Id],
[Mesc],
[Line],
[Unit],
[Description],
[ST_CODE],
[PbsNo],
[PbsDate],
[PbsQty],
[PbsQtyRec],
[QtyConsum1],
[QtyConsum2],
[QtyConsum3],
[QtyConsum4],
[QtyConsum5],
[Type],
[InvQty],
[TypeRequest]) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [LineNOIRHeaderId] ON [dbo].[Report4]
(
    [Line] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [HeaderId])
WHERE ([line]='I')
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [LineNoRHeaderId] ON [dbo].[Report4]
(
    [Line] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [HeaderId])
WHERE ([line]='H')
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [LineNoRMesc] ON [dbo].[Report4]
(
    [Line] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [Mesc])
WHERE ([line]='I')
WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [MescRAll] ON [dbo].[Report4]
(
    [Mesc] ASC
)
INCLUDE ( [Id],
[Line],
[Unit],
[Description],
[ST_CODE],
[PbsNo],
[PbsDate],
[PbsQty],
[PbsQtyRec],
[QtyConsum1],
[QtyConsum2],
[QtyConsum3],
[QtyConsum4],
[QtyConsum5],
[Type],
[InvQty],
[TypeRequest],
[HeaderId]) WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

i want run this Query for this table

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPSelectReport2] (@StringWhereParameter nvarchar(4000),@PageIndex int,@PageSize int )
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- َ Begin Of Transaction
begin tran

declare @from int=(@PageSize*(@PageIndex-1))+1
declare @to int=(@PageIndex*@PageSize)

declare @Query nvarchar(max)
set @Query=' select 

distinct id, [Mesc], [Line]
      ,[Unit]
      ,[Discription]
      ,[InvQty]
      ,[LastDateNil]
      ,[StCode]
      ,[PlanCode]
      ,[MIN]
      ,[MAX]
      ,[LastDateConsum]
      ,[PbsNo]
      ,[PbsDate]
      ,[PbsQty]
      ,[PbsQtyRec]
      ,[DateDelay]
      ,[TypeRequest]
      ,[HeaderId]
      ,LOCATION
 from (

SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Id) ROW_NUM
  FROM(
((SELECT Id,[Mesc]
      ,[Line]
      ,[Unit]
      ,[Discription]
      ,[InvQty]
      ,[LastDateNil]
      ,[StCode]
      ,[PlanCode]
      ,[MIN]
      ,[MAX]
      ,[LastDateConsum]
      ,[PbsNo]
      ,[PbsDate]
      ,[PbsQty]
      ,[PbsQtyRec]
      ,[DateDelay]
      ,[TypeRequest]
      ,[HeaderId]
      ,LOCATION
  FROM [MyMaterialDB].[dbo].[Report2]
  WHERE headerid IN(SELECT HeaderId FROM [MyMaterialDB].[dbo].[Report2] WHERE line=''H'''+ @StringWhereParameter+'))
  UNION
  (
    (SELECT Id,[Mesc]
      ,[Line]
      ,[Unit]
      ,[Discription]
      ,[InvQty]
      ,[LastDateNil]
      ,[StCode]
      ,[PlanCode]
      ,[MIN]
      ,[MAX]
      ,[LastDateConsum]
      ,[PbsNo]
      ,[PbsDate]
      ,[PbsQty]
      ,[PbsQtyRec]
      ,[DateDelay]
      ,[TypeRequest]
      ,[HeaderId]
      ,LOCATION
  FROM [MyMaterialDB].[dbo].[Report2]
  WHERE mesc IN(SELECT mesc FROM [MyMaterialDB].[dbo].[Report2] WHERE line=''I''' +@StringWhereParameter+'))
  UNION
  (SELECT Id, [Mesc]
      ,[Line]
      ,[Unit]
      ,[Discription]
      ,[InvQty]
      ,[LastDateNil]
      ,[StCode]
      ,[PlanCode]
      ,[MIN]
      ,[MAX]
      ,[LastDateConsum]
      ,[PbsNo]
      ,[PbsDate]
      ,[PbsQty]
      ,[PbsQtyRec]
      ,[DateDelay]
      ,[TypeRequest]
      ,[HeaderId]
      ,LOCATION
  FROM [MyMaterialDB].[dbo].[Report2]
  WHERE mesc IN(SELECT HeaderId FROM [MyMaterialDB].[dbo].[Report2] WHERE line=''I'''+@StringWhereParameter+')
  )))) a)b where b.ROW_NUM between '+CAST(@from as varchar(10))+' and '+CAST(@to as varchar(10))

  -- Order by Mesc,Line,unit
 exec(@Query)
 --print @Query

--


 if @@error = 0    
 Commit Tran    
 Else   
 rollback tran
End
```

into this table i have more then 1000000 records and when run this sp ,It takes ten minutes or more. How do I optimize the structure or query. please help me. thanks all.

Comment: why are you using dynamic sql ?
beside what data is in [MyMaterialDB].[dbo].[Report2] ? is it a table or a view ?

Comment: i using jqgrid plugin i want implement search jqgrid. and for implement search in jqgrid i have just one solution and this solution using dynamic query. and Report2 is table in MyMaterialDB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters you MUST do the following (I think only those actions can take your query execution time down to much less than a minute):

- remove every `in clause`. `select ... from ... where a in (select ...)` is a) very very very slow, b)dangerous as it can run your sql server out of memory -especially for large datasets like yours-. You must change all in clauses to `left outer joins`, it is very easy to do this.
- remove `distinct clause`. This forces your query to do order by (behind the schenes) and generally is very slow too. Try to rephrase your query so that records are already distinct
- As long as you have distinct data you must also change `union` to `union all`. Union is same as `distinct union` which goes as my previous statement. If you use `union all` you will see great improvement to your query... as long as you can bring your data to not needed to be distinct...

If you manage to make at least 2 of the 3 previous changes, i think you will see great improvement. If you can handle all of them, you will have a very fast query.

And also, do not bother changing your sql exec into a 'precompliled' stored procedure. I don't think you will gain an significant improvement by doing this (I see you have dynamic where so this wouldn't be applicant in any case).

Please, tell me if that worked.